# Windows Files-OnDemand Context menu item

Tags: .net, windows, windows-shell, shell-extensions

## Files On-Demand

We must prepare the application similar to OneDrive on Windows - synchronization list of files stored in cloud and synchronization of selected files.

During the investigation we found a very nice library to manage On-Demand Files in Windows from C# - [ShellBoost](https://www.shellboost.com/Doc/Introduction/Overview).

### List files from the cloud as local files

Show list of on-demand files in a local folder
[image: file-list]

Show folder with files as Namespace extension
[image: file-list-ext]

With [ShellBoost](https://www.shellboost.com/Doc/Introduction/Overview) we can synchronize files in a very cool way. We can show sync status, we can do all operations like on regular files, additionally, we can synchronize items or remove them from synchronization.

Unfortunately, we met some restrictions

### File Context Menu Items problem

We are not able to add custom actions to not synchronized files.
I used [SharpShell](https://github.com/dwmkerr/sharpshell) to manage additional context menu items on files - it works

[image: context-menu-on-sync-file]

But on not synchronized files it doesn't work.

[image: context-menu-on-not-sync-file]

#### OneDrive supports custom context menu item

Somehow OneDrive is able to add custom menu items

[image: onedrive-context-menu]

#### PowerToys can add a custom context menu item

Somehow PowerToys is able to add custom menu items to our not synchronized files

[image: powertoys-context-menu]

#### Example

Here is a repo with the example
https://github.com/m4tchl0ck/ShellBoost-My-Samples

Comment: Over a sync root, IContextMenu is deprecated. You must use an IExplorerCommand implementation (+ possibly app identity). And this will be the case for all file folders with Windows 11 anyway: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2021/07/19/extending-the-context-menu-and-share-dialog-in-windows-11/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the proper way to implement context menus over sync roots is using an [IExplorerCommand](https://%5B1%5D%20%5B1%5D:%20https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-iexplorercommand%5D) implementation.

However, there is at least the option to make your context menu (using [IContextMenu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-icontextmenu)) visible on cloud files as mentioned [here](https://github.com/microsoft/ProjFS-Managed-API/discussions/61) and in the  [DEFAULT_FOLDER_MENU_RESTRICTIONS enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/ne-shobjidl_core-default_folder_menu_restrictions#constants) documentation.

When registering your context menu handler in the registry, add a  `ContextMenuOptIn` value to your handler registration at `HKCU\CLSID\{YOUR-HANDLER-CLSID}`.

For example:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{FF360A3F-3789-4A0C-B5EC-9C843C8A7490}]
@="CoreCLR COMHost Server"
"ContextMenuOptIn"=""
```

The context menu will now also be shown on dehydrated placeholder files.